# DocuSign API SOAP API Documents without fields

Tags: soap, docusignapi

I'm having issue using DocuSign API. when I send a PDF via SOAP API. (I am using the method CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates, the templates are on your server) When the user received the envelope (PDF) the fields are not there. But when I send via the WEB they do have the fields. 
I was not adding the Role to the API, now I'm but still not showing the fields. 
Should I use the method CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms instead the other one?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're using the right method (**CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates**). The most likely reason that the fields (tabs) are not being displayed when you create the Envelope via the API is that the recipient Role Name(s) being specified by the API request does not *exactly* match the Role Name(s) specified by the Template itself (with which the tabs are associated). Make sure **spelling**, **spacing**, and **case** of Role Name(s) specified by your API request matches exactly with what's specified by the Template.